# Image from URL PHP

Tags: php, image, forms, save, fopen

I have this simple code

```
$img = '/inventory/books/' . $id . '.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($imageurl));
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($img)), $img);
```

Where `$id` is just a sha1 string, and `$imageurl` is a URL of any type of image from a HTML form.

When the script runs though, it doesn't save the image, and I have no clue why.

My PHP.ini has `allow_url_fopen` set to true, which seems to be the usual reason this fails.

Comment: Try and use a relative path `../inventory/books/` as an example or `inventory/books/` if running code from root, or full path `/var/user/you/public_html/inventory/books/` and check for folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

That did work Fred.

I just had to remove the first `/` in the file path, since it was in the same relative folder.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I should have put it as an answer ;)